# What is this network switch’s VLAN toggle-switch for?

Tags: ethernet, switch, vlan

I already use one of those cheap AliExpress 5-port ethernet switches. Conveniently, I can operate this switch on a 5V USB port.

Now I have seen that there is also an 8-port version. This has two strange features that I can't clearly identify from the description.

1. VLAN switch
2. Uplink labled port

Does anyone have any idea what this could be about, especially the VLAN switch?

One example of many selling the exact same model: https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005005565289406.html

Comment: Any reason why you did not bother with a quick search?

Comment: Couldn't finde the info I was searching for..

Comment: Hard to say without documentation... allow or disallow VLAN passthrough maybe? An "uplink" port is ancient and generally means that it is a cross-over (Tx/Rx reversed) port and no auto switching and something that hasn't been used for 15+ years as most switch have auto-MDI/MDI-x switching, implying the chipset used for the switch is ANCIENT (20 years old maybe). Why not just spend a little more and get something decent... an 8-port TP-Link unmanaged gigabit switch is like $20 USD, even a managed switch that support QoS, Vlan, IGMP and LAG is less than $30 USD

Comment: I don't think you tried. Search on those extact term, the first delivers `https://arstechnica.com/civis/threads/what-exactly-is-an-uplink-port.1006025/` at number 1 spot. For the second, further down the list is the ubiquitous `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLAN`

Comment: @acejavelin the documentation on these is ... interesting. That's to say non existant

Comment: I know what uplink port was back in the days... but doesn't make sense with auto-MDI/MDI-x

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That usually means the device design was “borrowed” (aka: ripped off) from another vendor. Wonder if there is a Netgear equivalent?

Comment: They are largely based off reference designs I suspect, saves on engineering costs. Most of the cheapies follow the same basic designs and chipsets

Comment: @acejavelin thanks for the recommendation, however it looks like TP-Link TL-SG108PE is more like $55 around here, or what model were you thinking of? It's not that I need any of the fancy features, the 5 port switch I already use is perfectly fine giving me 4 more ports where it is now. Edit: TP-Link TL-SG108E is $30, the other one was with PoE which I don't need.

Comment: I was referring to this one... in the US it is priced at $26..99 - https://www.amazon.com/Ethernet-Unmanaged-Shielded-Replacement-TL-SG108E/dp/B00K4DS5KU/ or this one that is $18.99 https://www.amazon.com/Ethernet-Splitter-Optimization-Unmanaged-TL-SG108/dp/B00A121WN6/ref=sr_1_5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual:

**VLAN: Port isolation mode, LINK/ACT ports cannot access each other, only communication with Uplink port.**

Manufacturer/Model is by the way: [DIEWU](https://aliexpress.com/store/4688104) [TXE197](https://aliexpress.com/item/4000203387080.html)

Answer (score 3):

It varies but in this case I *believe* it stops the 'regular' ethernet ports from talking to each other (kinda like client isolation on wireless connections), though in some other switches it may split up ports of different speeds into seperate domains.

Comment: Sort of "Client Isolation" is what that toggle was supposed to do on my own device too.  Except it didn't do anything at all. When I opened it I discovered the toggle wasn't connected to the PCB at all. Why they even bothered to put it in is beyond me. (My best guess is that they had a lot of these housings with the toggles pre-installed already in stock, but the feature was dropped in a later revision of the PCB. So they used the housings "as is" figuring that most customers would never notice.)

Comment: @Tonny your suspicion sounds convincing, would you care to give it as an answer?

Comment: Received the switch and read the manual. See answer I posted. Whether it does anything or not I didn't verify yet. I don't actually need client isolation anyway.